# When aplying exposed dropdown menu style for a dropdown menu on android studio my activity_main.xml disappears

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, drop-down-menu, material-design

I am trying to implement a dropdown menu on my app but anytime i try to choose any material option for style it makes the whole activity_main.xml disappear.

I have done it before in other projects that i use to test things before implementing in the final app and they work, i looked for any differences between projects but i dont find any.

this is the code snippet in the activity_main.xml

```
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                             style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:text="Chose level and press play"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/gomarice_coffee_jelly_umai"
                        android:textSize="30sp"/>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Here is the tutorial I followed: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exposed-drop-down-menu-in-android/

[photo so you can have an idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTO2t.jpg)

I have tried every materialDesign with the name dropdownmenu.
What I expect is to display a dropdown menu.
Im also having problem with other .xml file needed for the dropdownmenu
[This file has a disappeared background, so maybe it has something related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8nA1.jpg)

This is the first time i ask, hope the problem is clear enough, and sorry for the language mistakes, i'm from Spain.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in `AutoCompleteView`.
The `android:layout_height` should be `wrap_content` and not `match_parent`.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
  android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ...
/>
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, thanks for replying!

Comment: you could refer more from this [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Menu.md)

If textview is the issue. Have you tried by inserting default view for it and not the custom textview?